# Counting single instance of Items where its been mentioned multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

As you you can see below the deal one has multiple items in it. Now I want to sum Qty where Deal ID is the same but I do not want to have in my qty result multiple count of deal ID.

```
Order ID, Deal ID, Qty
1       , deal 1 , 1
1       , deal 1 , 1
3       , deal 2 , 1
4       , deal 1 , 1
4       , deal 1 , 1
5       , deal 2 , 1
```

Result I am looking for:

```
Deal ID, sum(Qty)
deal 1 , 2
deal 2 , 2
```

I tried to group them by both Deal ID and Order ID but that's not giving me anything...obviously!

```
SELECT `order_items`.`deal`, sum(order_items.qty) as qty
FROM (`order_items`)
JOIN `deals` ON `deals`.`deal` = `order_items`.`deal`
GROUP BY `order_items`.`deal`, `order_items`.`order_id`
ORDER BY `qty`
```

Comment: Just group by `deal` -- remove `order_id`... But with your sample data, shouldn't `deal 1` return 4 instead of 2?

Comment: I'm trying to count number of times each deal has been used, as you can see deal one has two items in it... and so the result should be 2 not 4,

Comment: I think instead you want `count(distinct orderid)` instead?

Comment: I think you are right... testing it now

Comment: @sgeddes count(distinct order_id) is what I was looking for; Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You just just `group by` the one column that you want to be unique on each row -- the `deal`.

I think your query would be easier to write and to read without the backticks and using table aliases:

```
SELECT oi.deal, sum(oi.qty) as qty
FROM order_items oi JOIN
     deals d
     ON d.deal = oi.deal
GROUP BY oi.deal;
ORDER BY qty ;
```

Also, `name` is not in your desired output, so it doesn't belong in the query.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT `Deal ID`, SUM(Qty) as Quantity FROM `order_items` GROUP BY `Deal
>   ID`

or

> SELECT `Deal ID`, COUNT(Qty) as Quantity FROM `order_items` GROUP BY `Deal
>   ID`

Depending on how you want to treat Qty. If Qty2 means it was used twice use sum, otherwise use count